# When trying to add one dataframe column to other dataframe its giving NAn

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to add one column from df1 to df2 but i got NAn , but in real for this column in df1 have value.

**here is my df1**

[image]

**here is my df2**

[image]

desired output:

[image]

But when i apply this piece of code:

```
df2['X']=df1['X']
```

I got this result:

[image]

Comment: index different , try df2['X']=df1['X'].values

Comment: @Wen-Ben , Thanks ,index was not same after adding .values problem solved

Comment: let me write a answer about it

Comment: ok , and one more thing , if X in real is NAn then it will not give error ?

Comment: It will not raise error

Comment: @Wen-Ben, ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index. when its X is empty in real its giving this error

Comment: You need to make sure df1 and df2 length is same

Comment: when X have value then df1 and df2 length is same , but when there is no value in X then length is not same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:

Index was not same for `df1` and `df2` , due to index sensitivity of pandas occurred this problem , one memeber @wenben give suggestion to add `.values` it solved partial problem but when length for `df1` and `df2` not same `.values` will throw error.

**Solution:**

just reset index of `df1` and `df2` for making same index.

```
df1.reset_index(drop=True)
df2.reset_index(drop=True)
```